# Using closest() and $(this) to select elements

Tags: jquery

I started learning jquery just recently and I'm trying to use the `closest()` method and `$(this)` to find the closest class "ion-loading-c" and add a class to it. I'm getting no errors so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is my javascipt:

```
$(function(){
  $('.ion-plus').click(function(e) {
      $(this).closest('.ion-loading-c').addClass('blue');
  });
});
```

and this is my HTML:

```
<i class="icon ion-loading-c"></i>

<a href="{{ URL::route('purchase') }}/{{ $i->id }}">
    <span class="text-content">
        <div class="image-row">
            <i class="icon ion-plus ion-icon-add"></i>
            <i class="icon ion-heart ion-icon-add"></i>
        </div>
        <div id="id" class="hidden cart-add-ajax">{{ $i->id }}</div>
        <div class="image-row image-text">
            <span>{{ $i->item }}</span>
        </div>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Where is an element with class `'.ion-loading-c`

Comment: Sorry about that. For some reason the line was at the top of the html I inserted and it wasnt showing up in the post....weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `.ion-loading-c` does not have a direct relationship to `.ion-plus` - use `closest` and `prev`:

```
$('.ion-plus').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('a').prev(".ion-loading-c").addClass('blue');
});
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!!!! I was stressing out so much over this issue! You made my day man!

Comment: How can I replace the class with another class like this example does?:    $('.dataItem').removeClass('ready').addClass('waiting');

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem

```
$(function(){
  $('.ion-plus').click(function(e) {
    var $this;
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.has(".ion-loading-c")) {
      return $(this).closest('.ion-loading-c').addClass('blue');
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you know how can I replace the class with another class like this example does?: $('.dataItem').removeClass('ready').addClass('waiting');

Comment: $(function(){
  $('.dataItem').click(function(e) {
    var $this;
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.has(".dataItem")) {
      return $(this).removeClass('ready').addClass('waiting');
  });
});